# .getValues() not working if values created by formula Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This program works perfectly except getting a row of data. It always grabs a blank set. Anyone see what I'm missing? It should be simple to copy and paste a silly row.

I need to grab the data from D:BA in the edited row. Next, delete the formula that created the data, then paste the saved data back in the row so I can customize it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart != 1 ||
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Loads")
     /*e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Loads") || 
     e.range.rowStart != 9 || e.range.columnStart != 1 ||
     e.range.rowEnd != 53 || 
     e.range.columnEnd != 1*/
    ){ 
    return;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loads");
    var arr = [];
    var r = e.range.getRow();
    var cell1 = sheet.getRange(r,1);
    var cell2 = sheet.getRange(r,2);
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var row = sheet.getRange(r,4,49,49);
    var value = e.value;
    var arr = [];

    // get cell 2
    var cell2value = cell2.getValue();
    // delete cell
    cell2.clear();
    //paste formula
    cell2.setFormula('=split(REGEXREPLACE(A'+r+',\",\",\", \"),\",\",true)');

    // copy row r,3,1,40
    //var row2 = sheet.getRange(r,4,1,10);
    var rowValues = row.getValues();

    //push row values to array
    arr.push(rowValues);
    // clear e.range
    cell1.clear();  
    // delete cell
    cell2.clear();
    // paste cell
    //cell2.setValue(cell2value);
    // paste row
    row.setValues(arr);
  }
};
```

Comment: First impression: Are you sure it's running at all?  Your `if()` condition has no `else`, so if it's true it calls `return` & gives you nothing, & there's nothing to execute if the condition evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

First, your logic never gets executed: if your `if()` condition evaluates to `true`, `onEdit(e)` executes `return` & nothing else happens, otherwise (when `if()` evaluates to `false`) there is no other code to execute. You probably mean `if(!foo){ return; }`, otherwise you need to add an `else` clause.  Also, your `if()` condition will evaluate to true if, for example, cell A1 on any sheet other 'Loads' is edited: i'm not sure that this is what you want. You may want to use logical AND here.

Next, you are only grabbing the data from your 'Loads' sheet: you never reference the row in the edited sheet. You probably need 2 sheet objects: one for the sheet that was edited, which you can get with [`ss.getActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveSheet()) & the second for 'Loads'.

You are also grabbing a 49x49 array when you call [`sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), which means that your `range.getValues()` calls are also returning a 49x49 array of values, which is not what your description says you want to do. Do you mean `sheet.getRange(r,4,1,49)`? (Which returns a 1x49 array.)

`arr.push(rowValues)` is complicating matters by pushing your 2D array `rowValues` into a new array element in `arr[]`, making `arr[]` a 3D array (`arr[0]` contains the 49x49 array `rowValues`). If you need to copy `rowValues` to another variable, just assign it: `var arr = rowValues;`

Are you trying to clear the formula form `cell2`? If so, you'll need set an empty formula, as [`range.clear()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear()) leaves formulas in tact.

Everything else appears to work fine, but i'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  I hope this helps, tho.

Comment: I would like to point out that the problem is not the lack of an `else` clause. You can have an `if()` with no `else` and run just fine, the problem is where the bracket is. My understanding that he wants to do a `if(/*reasons*/) { return }` which is completely normal if you want to kill the function if the conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks, @Vytautas, you're absolutely right. Don't know why i didn't look at it from that perspective: yours is a much better explanation of early `return` issue. I've updated my answer to include your insight.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes the if clause seems to be working well.

Comment: Yes it needs to be a 1x49 array and I will delete the extra var to clean that up.

Comment: So I broke this down to just the part where it sets the formula. I couldn't see it as the full program but the formula was throwing errors. Solving that helped me clean that up and prevent the errors.